# Usar um Controller para conectar rotas com funções assíncronas [Node]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Boa noite!

Estou com dúvidas sobre algo que aparenta ser fácil, mas não estou conseguindo sair do lugar. A ideia seria realizar utilizar o método GET para recuperar os usuários do banco de dados, mas gostaria de utilizar MVC para isso.
Seguindo em teoria o conceito do MVC, minha rota chamaria meu Controller, e ele chamaria a minha função assíncrona no Model. Se eu chamo diretamente minha função assíncrona na rota pelo Model ele funciona, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que o Controller seja o "intermédio".

**Minha rota:**

Aqui deixei apenas duas rotas configuradas para teste, e elas chamariam o controller abaixo.

```
const express = require('express');
const UsersController = require('./controllers/UsersController');
const AccountController = require('./controllers/AccountController');
const routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/users', UsersController.testeIndex);
routes.post('/users', UsersController.testeCreate);
//routes.delete('/users/:id_user', UsersController.deletetUsers);

//routes.get('/account', AccountController.index);
//routes.post('/account', AccountController.create);

module.exports = routes;
```

**Meu controller:**

Aqui a ideia seria fazer com que o controller apenas chame a função do model e retorne as informações pra rota. (Neste caso iria fazer a busca dos usuário com sucesso no banco de dados)

```
const UserDAO = require('../models/database/UsersDAO');

module.exports = {
    testeIndex : async function(req, res) {
        var index = await UserDAO.index;
        return res.json(index);

    },
    testeCreate : async function(req, res) {
        var create = await UserDAO.create;
        return res.json(console.log(create));
    }
};
```

**Meu model (neste caso, está um DAO):**

Se na rota eu chamar diretamente este arquivo e as funções dele funciona perfeitamente, mas acredito que isto fuja do conceito do MVC

```
const connection = require('./connection');

module.exports = {
    async index(request, response) {
        const users = await connection('users').select('*');
        return (response.json(users));
    },

    async create(request, response) {
        const { usuario, senha } = request.body;
        //Testar criptografia mais tarde
        await connection('users').insert({
            usuario,
            senha
        });
        return response.json({usuario, senha});
    },
}
```

Não tenho retorno no Insomnia quando uso o GET, nem erro no projeto

[image: Não tenho retorno no Insomnia quando uso o GET, nem erro no projeto]

Comment: Quando você faz `var index = await UserDAO.index`, você está atribuindo a referência do método `UserDAO.index`  à variável `index`. Se você quiser executar a função, você deve invocá-la. Para isso, faça `var index = await UserDAO.index()`.

Comment: Além do que já foi dito, recomendo dar uma olhada nesse módulo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler

Comment: Além disso... O DAO não deveria receber o `req` e `res`, apenas os dados necessários para a ação no banco (cadastro, alteração, etc)